# Need prompt to save changes in Windows form when changing displayed record

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am relatively new to programming, so this may be an easy one. I have a Windows form that connects to SQL Server and displays the data in a form where a user can edit and add or delete records (via databinding). The form works well, and has record navigation controls as well as context menus that allow the user to filter data on any field.

Currently, the user can make changes and switch to new records, etc... but changes are not applied until the user clicks the "save" button. However, I'd like to prompt the user to save records whenever the user navigates to a new record (either through navigator or through application of a filter which displays a different record).

What event can I use that will trigger whenever a different record is reflected in the form?

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about checking whether the data in the inputs is different to the ones loaded from the database in the beginning and if the user navigates away and the data has changed, show your desired popup?

Comment: Hi Capricorn - At this time, I am only trying to determine how to trigger an event when a different record is viewed in the form. I tried RowChanged but that does not trigger when the record changes due to a filter being applied. (Also, I had problems when using the RowChanged event to trigger a save - as the save would then trigger the RowChanged event multiple times...). How can I trigger an event  whenever a new record is displayed? I would think this should be a common issue for any data form...?

Comment: I also tried "CurrentChanged" event, but that triggers after the record is moved to the next record. I need an event that triggers before the move (for example, if there was a "CurrentChanging" event...).